# Error when installing pytext-nlp : ERROR: No matching distribution found for torch==1.3.1 (from pytext-nlp)

Tags: python-3.x, torch, pytext

This is the error message:

```
tf2) C:\WINDOWS\system32>pip install pytext-nlp
Collecting pytext-nlp
  Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/83/a6/8802bbfa7e1ded46d873d980ea6d0654c5d2268af2daea77f51d4ec9314f/pytext_nlp-0.3.1-py3-none-any.whl
Requirement already satisfied: docutils==0.15.2 in c:\users\alienware\anaconda3\envs\tf2\lib\site-packages (from pytext-nlp) (0.15.2)
Requirement already satisfied: Markdown==3.1.1 in c:\users\alienware\anaconda3\envs\tf2\lib\site-packages (from pytext-nlp) (3.1.1)
Collecting onnx==1.5.0
  Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/e3/60/afe38e81d39109a545e4533bca8efcad48d4c616ec8be8bf46aed620f4e2/onnx-1.5.0-cp37-cp37m-win_amd64.whl
Requirement already satisfied: Werkzeug==0.16.0 in c:\users\alienware\anaconda3\envs\tf2\lib\site-packages (from pytext-nlp) (0.16.0)
Requirement already satisfied: Cython==0.29.14 in c:\users\alienware\anaconda3\envs\tf2\lib\site-packages (from pytext-nlp) (0.29.14)
Collecting absl-py==0.9.0
  Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/1a/53/9243c600e047bd4c3df9e69cfabc1e8004a82cac2e0c484580a78a94ba2a/absl-py-0.9.0.tar.gz
Collecting idna==2.8
  Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/14/2c/cd551d81dbe15200be1cf41cd03869a46fe7226e7450af7a6545bfc474c9/idna-2.8-py2.py3-none-any.whl
Requirement already satisfied: readme-renderer==24.0 in c:\users\alienware\anaconda3\envs\tf2\lib\site-packages (from pytext-nlp) (24.0)
Collecting twine==3.1.1
  Downloading https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/99/94/08b3b933c611416dad89c8abcc94a6d6c29e8609987235b6e7f10b42de82/twine-3.1.1-py3-none-any.whl
Requirement already satisfied: webencodings==0.5.1 in c:\users\alienware\anaconda3\envs\tf2\lib\site-packages (from pytext-nlp) (0.5.1)
Collecting numpy==1.18.1
  Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/a9/38/f6d6d8635d496d6b4ed5d8ca4b9f193d0edc59999c3a63779cbc38aa650f/numpy-1.18.1-cp37-cp37m-win_amd64.whl
Collecting more-itertools==8.1.0
  Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/bc/e2/3206a70758a21f9878fcf9478282bb68fbc66a5564718f9ed724c3f2bb52/more_itertools-8.1.0-py3-none-any.whl
Collecting typing==3.7.4.1
  Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/fe/2e/b480ee1b75e6d17d2993738670e75c1feeb9ff7f64452153cf018051cc92/typing-3.7.4.1-py3-none-any.whl
Requirement already satisfied: scipy==1.4.1 in c:\users\alienware\anaconda3\envs\tf2\lib\site-packages (from pytext-nlp) (1.4.1)
Requirement already satisfied: jmespath==0.9.4 in c:\users\alienware\anaconda3\envs\tf2\lib\site-packages (from pytext-nlp) (0.9.4)
Collecting six==1.14.0
  Downloading https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/65/eb/1f97cb97bfc2390a276969c6fae16075da282f5058082d4cb10c6c5c1dba/six-1.14.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl
Collecting hypothesis==3.88.3
  Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/3a/42/f33701a2aa10a4396485afa331862945d26871177e984d6a9d8d0a91739f/hypothesis-3.88.3-py3-none-any.whl
Collecting pytorch-pretrained-bert==0.6.2
  Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/d7/e0/c08d5553b89973d9a240605b9c12404bcf8227590de62bae27acbcfe076b/pytorch_pretrained_bert-0.6.2-py3-none-any.whl
Collecting portalocker==1.5.2
  Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/91/db/7bc703c0760df726839e0699b7f78a4d8217fdc9c7fcb1b51b39c5a22a4e/portalocker-1.5.2-py2.py3-none-any.whl
Collecting regex==2019.11.1
  Downloading https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/5a/2e/391b828ffe99c907e215f6ac2652558754a4a26559f36e55c05292945e41/regex-2019.11.1-cp37-none-win_amd64.whl (313kB)
     |████████████████████████████████| 317kB 1.1MB/s
Requirement already satisfied: pytz==2019.3 in c:\users\alienware\anaconda3\envs\tf2\lib\site-packages (from pytext-nlp) (2019.3)
Collecting s3transfer==0.3.0
  Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/d5/29/2a79d0223617d255eccac5fd9c147d65ee32f9aabe0e47ab75fd7568af24/s3transfer-0.3.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl
Requirement already satisfied: chardet==3.0.4 in c:\users\alienware\anaconda3\envs\tf2\lib\site-packages (from pytext-nlp) (3.0.4)
Collecting fairseq==0.9.0
  Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/67/bf/de299e082e7af010d35162cb9a185dc6c17db71624590f2f379aeb2519ff/fairseq-0.9.0.tar.gz
Collecting protobuf==3.11.2
  Downloading https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/30/c6/286db43e2d0d4b89d328a222365c7a253a99a24067812253f0d4f8eb0f1c/protobuf-3.11.2-cp37-cp37m-win_amd64.whl (1.0MB)
     |████████████████████████████████| 1.0MB 435kB/s
Collecting typing-extensions==3.7.4.1
  Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/03/92/705fe8aca27678e01bbdd7738173b8e7df0088a2202c80352f664630d638/typing_extensions-3.7.4.1-py3-none-any.whl
Collecting pkginfo==1.5.0.1
  Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/e6/d5/451b913307b478c49eb29084916639dc53a88489b993530fed0a66bab8b9/pkginfo-1.5.0.1-py2.py3-none-any.whl
Collecting sentencepiece==0.1.85
  Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/61/c5/e7e2f45c076097ac1a58b21288be25ae4eb4044be899e6c04cd897a00f15/sentencepiece-0.1.85-cp37-cp37m-win_amd64.whl
Collecting joblib==0.14.1
  Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/28/5c/cf6a2b65a321c4a209efcdf64c2689efae2cb62661f8f6f4bb28547cf1bf/joblib-0.14.1-py2.py3-none-any.whl
Collecting tensorboard==1.14.0
  Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/91/2d/2ed263449a078cd9c8a9ba50ebd50123adf1f8cfbea1492f9084169b89d9/tensorboard-1.14.0-py3-none-any.whl
Requirement already satisfied: attrs==19.3.0 in c:\users\alienware\anaconda3\envs\tf2\lib\site-packages (from pytext-nlp) (19.3.0)
Requirement already satisfied: python-dateutil==2.8.0 in c:\users\alienware\anaconda3\envs\tf2\lib\site-packages (from pytext-nlp) (2.8.0)
ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement torch==1.3.1 (from pytext-nlp) (from versions: 0.1.2, 0.1.2.post1, 0.1.2.post2)
ERROR: No matching distribution found for torch==1.3.1 (from pytext-nlp)
```

Answer (score 0):

The location where it is trying to get the pytorch 1.3.1 from is https://pypi.org/simple/torch which doesn't contain any wheel files for Windows. You can install pytorch manually (see instructions at https://pytorch.org/get-started/locally/), but make sure that it is version 1.3.1. After that the pytext-nlp installation should work.